# Assigning border-image-width with shorthand border-image property

Tags: css

I am trying to see the function of the shorthand border-image property. However there are some points I couldn't understand. I don't know how the browser will understand If I use a lenght as border-image-width or border-image-outset. Therefore I decided to look the syntax and make some experiments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384064(v=vs.85).aspx

This site shows a syntax including square brackets. However I couldn't make it work with any of the below:

```
border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 50px round;
border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 [50px] round;
border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 [/50px] round;
```

When I change the 50px value nothing happens (actually the former two also prevents other properties to work properly)

I am using the example in the W3Schools during my modifications.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

Could someone show me an example which assign border-image-width property with shorthand border-image property?

I can do the job width border-image-width property but I want to understand the shorthand property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the constructs in the question are invalid, as you can check with the [W3C CSS Validato](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator)r.

The brackets on the cited page are metanotations, echoing the [notational conventions of CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/about.html#property-defs) as well as Candidate Recommendation that defines [`border-width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-image).

If you wish to include border image width, as it seems, you need to write a slash `/` (which is part of the CSS syntax) but no brackets (which are metanotations used for grouping):

```
border-image: url(border.png) 30 30 /50px round;
```

Comment: To be more precise, the notation is a BNF (Backus - Naur Form) variant. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form#Variants . Brackets mean 'optional'

Comment: @vals, no, CSS 2.1 says “Brackets ([ ]) are for grouping.” Optionality is expressed with “?”.